# Strong Triadic Closure Violate

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Strong Triadic Closure]

both e-b and e-d are s, a-c is w, so b-d should be w
but the teacher said its wrong

I am very confused what nodes satisfy and violate Strong Triadic Closure

Comment: Which book you got the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We say that a node A violates the Strong Triadic Closure Property if
>   it has strong ties to two other nodes B and C, and there is no edge at
>   all (either a strong or weak tie) between B and C. We say that a node
>   A satisfies the Strong Triadic Closure Property if it does not violate
>   it.

The answer says b and d violates. That is because a-b and b-e are s, but there is no edge connecting a-e. Similarly, d violates the Strong Triadic Closure Property because c-d and d-e are s, but there is no edge connecting c-e?